# Central forces and conservation problem

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

An object A moves under the influence of a planet B's gravity, a central force of magnitude $\frac{1}{r^2}$. At some point, its velocity is $u$**e**$_{\theta}$ and $r=a$. It is given that $au^2 < 2$. I am looking to find an upper limit to the distance A gets from B.

Integrating the force I found the potential energy to be V = $-\frac{1}{r}$.

From conservation of angular momentum I found that:
**L** = $au$**k** = $r^2\dot{\theta}$**k** $\implies$ $\dot{\theta} = \frac{au}{r^2}$.

From conservation of energy I found that:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2}\Big(\dot{r}^2 + r^2\dot{\theta}^2\Big) - \frac{1}{r} = \frac{\dot{r}^2}{2} + \frac{a^2u^2}{2r^2} - \frac{1}{r} = \frac{u^2}{2} - \frac{1}{a}.
\end{equation*}

If I use that $\frac{\dot{r}^2}{2} \geq 0$, simplify everything and use $au^2 < 2$ then I end up with:
\begin{equation*}
au^2(r^2 -a^2) -2r^2 +2ar \geq 0 \implies 2a(r-a) \geq 0.
\end{equation*}

So at this point I only have $r \geq a$, but that only gives me a lower bound for this distance, right? If someone could point out where I'm going wrong that would be great.

Comment: Perhaps this question was more suited to Physics.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the condition that at $r=a$ the velocity is $u$**e**$_{\theta}$ means that when $r=a$ we are either at a minimum distance or at a maximum distance.

This is because the condition that marks that we are at an extreme distance is $\dot{r} = 0$, i.e., no radial velocity.

So, from the equation
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\dot{r}^2}{2} + \frac{a^2u^2}{2r^2} - \frac{1}{r} = \frac{u^2}{2} - \frac{1}{a}
\end{equation*}

Using $\dot{r} = 0$ and after multiplying by $2 a r^2$ gives
\begin{equation*}
a^3u^2 - 2 a r = (a u^2 - 2 ) r^2 
\end{equation*}

Which has as solutions
\begin{equation*}
r = a \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - (2 - a u^2)a u^2}}{2 - a u^2}
\end{equation*}

Hence
\begin{equation*}
r = a \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{(1 - a u^2)^2}}{2 - a u^2}
\end{equation*}

And, finally
\begin{equation*}
r = a \vee r = \frac{a^2 u^2}{2 - a u^2} >  a 
\end{equation*}

So, the lower bound for $r$ is $a$ and the upper bound for $r$ is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a^2 u^2}{2 - a u^2}
\end{equation*}

Comment: But this is a lower bound for $r$, and hence a 'lower limit' for this distance AB right? Whereas I am trying to find an upper bound for this 'upper limit', unless my understanding of what this question asks is off

Comment: @AzamatBagatov: I added a clarification in the end of my post. The second value is the upper bound.